# how to write stored procedure to execute queries via call

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures

how to write stored procedure to execute queries via call. for e.g

```
CALL splitter("insert into customer(num1,num2) VALUES ('2','4')  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE num1=num1+7,num2=num2+1;");
```

I have a procedure:

```
PROCEDURE `splitter`(inputsql TEXT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE X  INT;
    DECLARE Y INT;
    DECLARE ssql VARCHAR(10000);
SET Y = LENGTH(inputsql) - LENGTH(REPLACE(inputsql, '\n', '')) + 1;
SET X = 1;
WHILE X  <= Y DO
 SET @ssql = SPLIT_STRING(inputsql,'\n',X);
        PREPARE stmt FROM @ssql;
        EXECUTE stmt;
         SET  X = X + 1; 
 END WHILE;
```

i get following error

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DU' at line 1

Comment: i have a feeling you are mixing MySQL syntax with SQL Server (MSSQL) syntax as `SPLIT_STRING` is SQL Server valid function, unless you have created this function?

Comment: See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) for providing example data and expected results.. At least provide us with `SHOW CREATE TABLE customer` and the `SHOW CREATE FUNCTION SPLIT_STRING` so we can test..

Comment: Also keep in mind that this does nothing to protect against SQL injection, they are still possible with `PREPARE / EXECUTE`